# The timer job for this operation has been created, but it will fail

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, timer-jobs, stsadm

When I try to run the *upgrade solution* command on my server I get following error:

> The timer job for this operation has been created, but it will fail because the
>       administrative service for this server is not enabled. If the timer job is scheduled to run at a later time, you can run the jobs all at once using `stsadm.exe -o execadmsvcjobs`. To avoid this problem in the future, enable the Windows SharePoint Services administrative service, or run your operation through the `STSADM.exe` command line utility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please follow steps given below to ensure SharePoint Administration Services is available:

1. Click on Start->Run->Services.msc.
2. Search for "SharePoint 2010 Administration" service and make sure Status is `Started`.
3. If it is not enabled, start the service and re-execute the command.